# How to represent vertical alignment of syntax of code using BNF, EBNF or etc.?

Tags: syntax, indentation, bnf, ebnf, vertical-text

How to say that (in BNF, EBNF, etc) any two or more letters are placed in the same vertical alignment

e.g In python 2.x, we have what we call `indentation`.

```
def hello():
    print "hello," 
    print "world"

hello()
```

**Note** letter `p` (second line) is placed in the same vertical alignment of letter `p` (third line)

Further example (in markdown):

```
MyHeader
========
topic
-----
```

**Note** `M` and the first `=` are placed in the same vertical alignment (also `r` and last `=`, t and first `-`, `c` and last `-`)

My question is **How to represent these vertical alignment of letters using BNF, EBNF or etc.?**

**Further note:**
My point of this question is searching for a representation method to represent a vertical alignment of code, not just want to know how to write BNF or EBNF of `Python` or `Markdown`.

Comment: Given that BNF is capable of representing *context-free* grammars, you might have a bit of difficulty using them to represent a grammar that is not, in fact, context-free... `python` is not entirely context free; parts of it are, but the language as a whole is not.

Comment: Any other ways you can answer me below i just want the solution that can represent the vertical alignment of code.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can parse an indentation-sensitive language (like Python or Haskell) by using a little hack, which is well-described in the Python language reference's chapter on [lexical analysis](https://docs.python.org/3.3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#indentation). As described, the lexical analyzer turns leading whitespace into `INDENT` and `DEDENT` tokens [Note 1], which are then used in the Python grammar in a straightforward fashion. Here's a small excerpt:

```
suite         ::=  stmt_list NEWLINE | NEWLINE INDENT statement+ DEDENT
statement     ::=  stmt_list NEWLINE | compound_stmt
stmt_list     ::=  simple_stmt (";" simple_stmt)* [";"]
while_stmt    ::=  "while" expression ":" suite ["else" ":" suite]
```

So if you are prepared to describe (or reference) the lexical analysis algorithm, the BNF is simple.

However, you cannot actually write that algorithm as a context free grammar, because it is not context-free. (I'll leave out the proof, but it's similar to the proof that `anbncn` is not context free, which you can find in most elementary formal language textbooks, and all over the internet.)

[ISO standard EBNF](http://www.iso.org/iso/catalogue_detail.htm?csnumber=26153) (a free PDF is available) provides a way of including "extensions which a user may require": a `Special-sequence`, which is any text not containing a <kbd>?</kbd> surrounded on both sides by a <kbd>?</kbd>. So you could abuse the notation by including [Note 2]:

```
DEDENT = ? See section 2.1.8 of https://docs.python.org/3.3/reference/ ? ;
```

Or you could insert a full description of the algorithm. Of course, neither of those techniques will allow a parser generator to produce an accurate lexical analyzer, but it would be a reasonable way of communicating intent to a human reader.

It's worth noting that EBNF itself uses a special sequence to define one of its productions:

```
(* see 4.7 *) syntactic exception
   = ? a syntactic-factor that could be replaced
       by a syntactic-factor containing no
       meta-identifiers
     ? ;
```

---

#### Notes

1. The lexical analyzer also converts *some* physical newline characters into `NEWLINE` tokens, while making other newline characters vanish.
2. EBNF normally uses the syntax `=` rather than `::=` for a production, and insists that they be terminated with `;`. Comments are enclosed between `(*` and `*)`.

Comment: Great answer that is!

Comment: I'm not quite clear... does it mean that the result after pre-processing with lexical-analyzer can be described by context-free grammar?  but that what the lexical-analyzer itself does cannot be?

Comment: @anentropic: That's what it means. The lexical analyser needs to have a stack of indent positions, and you cannot represent such a stack in a CFG.